# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled. isScrap:false isAttached:true

Tags: java, android, scala, android-recyclerview

**App is crashing when more than 1 item is added to the recycler view with  IllegalArgumentException exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled. isScrap:false isAttached:true
```

Here is the full stack trace of the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled. isScrap:false isAttached:true
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleViewHolderInternal(RecyclerView.java:4624)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.quickRecycleScrapView(RecyclerView.java:4697)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.removeAndRecycleScrapInt(RecyclerView.java:6811)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2934)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14849)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14849)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1627)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14849)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14849)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14849)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14849)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14849)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14849)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14849)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2044)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1801)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1057)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5666)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5065)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using Scala Android to build the Android App.

I used case class for ViewHolder and Layout

Problem got fixed when i removed case class and made it normal class